# Accessing Other Tenants Data via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an Azure tenant and the Azure portal has partner access to all my clients. My requirement is to fetch contracts of each of my partner using the Microsoft Graph API.

I created an application inside my azure instance following the documentation guide. Am able to obtain an access token using https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token endpoint (where tenant id will be my azure tenant id) for the GraphAPI resource and am able to use the GraphAPI rest calls to fetch the contracts as well as the subscribedSkus of my tenant.

However how can i access the subscribesSkus of my clients?. Do i need the tenant id of each of my clients and obtain the access token for each client using the endpoint mentioned above? Does that means i need to create an app on all of my clients azure active directory instance?

Several references for similar scenarios like this can be found across the  internet but there is no concrete documentation available in microsoft which assists me to proceed further. 
Any insights into this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, you need to have credentials and obtain a token for each of the tenants you wish to access.

Comment: What about the application (for accessing the graph api) which needs to be created in the azure portal? Each individual client azure instance needs one?

Comment: No, that is handled automatically. You simply register as multi-tenant or use https://apps.dev.microsoft.com (which is always multi-tenant).

Comment: Thanks for the input. However is there a simple explanation of how a user can interact with a multi tenant application whose scope is just to use the graph api and therein use the graph rest api further to fetch the subscribedskus of each tenant.

Comment: I have created a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289307/microsoft-graph-api-single-vs-multi-tenant-app seeking help on this