# Why do i need to create a Multi-Tenant App?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have been doing some R&D on using the MicrosoftGraphAPI to fetch the skus subscribed by my organization.

I have created an app as described [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application). I did all the steps in the above link except 'Assign application to role'.

Using postman am able to get the oauth2 token by sending a post request using the link
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/&lt;mytenantid&gt;/oauth2/token`
with the client_id, client_secret, resource(`https://graph.microsoft.com`) and grant_type(`client_credentials`) parameters.

After this token is obtained I can fire a get request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus` with the Authorization header set as `Bearer {token}` which will return the SKUs subscribed by my organization.
So far so good. :-)

Now the requirement is I need to fetch the subscribed SKUs by one of the client (let's say having the azure ad tenant id 'ABCDEFG') of my organization.
I can successfully do that by registering an app in the client's tenant 'ABCDEFG' with the same steps as above. 
This approach is fine if my organization has say 1 or 2 clients.
However, if the client numbers are more than say 30 this approach of registering an application in each Azure AD instance is not feasible.

If the application that I registered in my organizations AAD was multi-tenant then how should it help me? 
What will be the steps needed to obtain the access token for each tenant?
Can somebody assist with some detailed explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need application-level access, you would assign one of the Application permissions listed in the documentation for getting SKUs: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscribedsku_list.

> Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All

In this case you should require the Read Directory Data (Directory.Read.All) application permission.

Then you mark your app as multi-tenanted.

Now then in order for another org to use your app, they will have to be on-boarded.
You will need some kind of page where their administrator can click a button/link to start using your app.
This should redirect the admin to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=your-client-id&prompt=admin_consent&response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=url-where-to-send-user-back
```

Once they sign in, they will be presented with a consent screen, where they can approve the permissions that your app requires.
If and when they do that, they will be redirected back to your app (to the URL you specified) and you can use the Id token to know which Azure AD tenant registered.

During this process a service principal for your app is created in their tenant, and the required permission is granted to it.
This means you can then get an access token for their tenant from: (using the same credentials)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/their-tenant-id/oauth2/token
```

Remember that access tokens are specific to an Azure AD tenant, so you will have to get an access token for each tenant.

One thing I would like to point out is that you should instead try to use delegated permissions if possible.
The application permission given here gives quite large access to your app, and some admins might not use your service for that reason alone.
Delegated permissions are more complex to handle, but allow your app to act on behalf of a user instead of purely as itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to give a proper explanation. The intention of the app that i registered in my organizations azure ad instance is that it just helps me to use the microsoft graph rest api. This app doesnt have any page or any code or anything. Its just a configuration which gives me a client id and client secret key (also has permissions set) which can be used to obtain the access token using the url https://login.microsoftonline.com/&lt;mytenantid&gt;/oauth2/token. <to be continued in another comment>

Comment: <continuation of my previous comment> By making this app multitenant, i assume this app should also be automatically available in other clients azure ad instances right?.  Why did you quote that 'Now then in order for another org to use your app, they will have to be on-boarded'.  Am really confused with the way microsoft has explained the 'multi-tenant' functionality.

Comment: Am awaiting your reply on the above comments. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah so the way it works is that multi-tenant apps do not automatically become available in other tenants. An admin has to go through the consent flow to make it available there.

Comment: What it means is that either you need to have some kind of on-boarding web page or you can just give them the link that makes them go through the consent flow. But then you would still need their tenant id after that so you can keep track which tenants have enabled the app.

Comment: I do have all tenantids of my  organizational clients with me. The problem is that I dont have a UI through which i can ask other tenants admins to give the consent. Reason is that I have a java web application which is local to my organizations infrastructre and am i am trying to implement a scheduled job(so no UI anywhere in the picture) which will fetch the required informations from azure ad instances using the graph api. Is this not doable?

Comment: It's possible to do. You would send them the link to Azure AD authorization endpoint containing `prompt=admin_consent` and once they are done with that, you'll be able to make the calls to Graph API. You might want to make the redirect URL something like your company's web page or some other landing page if you have one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt reply and am glad that it worked finally.. I will accept this as an answer and i will also post a separate answer explaining in detail the way i resolved this, which might assist other devs who might be looking for some solutions like this. Thanks again!!..

Comment: @active_coder, how did you solve your problem? I have absolutely the same situation, but cannot find a solution anywhere.